# How can I make beep sound through speakers(spdif)?

Tags: alsa

I want to `beep` through speakers. I'm using alsa through S/PDIF of ESI Julia.
User is in the audio group.

```
ls /dev/snd
controlC0  midiC0D0  pcmC0D0c  pcmC0D0p  pcmC0D1c  pcmC0D1p  seq  timer
```

If I try `beep -e /dev/snd/`* - all devices return this:

```
ioctl: Inappropriate ioctl for device
ioctl: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I'm shure it's `/dev/snd/pcmC0D1p` that I need, it's the only one busy when music is playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beep` tool controls the PC speaker, i.e., the tiny speaker on the motherboard itself.

Other sound devices cannot be controlled by `beep`.
You have to play some actual sound file, or synthesize the sound on the fly (try using the `synth` effect of [sox](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sox)).

Comment: Isn't `beep -e [device]` mean that I can use other devices besides motherboard's speaker?

Comment: That can be any device that supports the specific ioctl used to control the PC speaker. Only terminal devices connected to the console support this.

Answer (score 1):

Freedesktop compatible desktop systems should have the following directory installed:  `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/`.  This directory should contain default sound files used by your desktop.

Now to emit sound from your speaks, you can use `mplayer`:

```
mplayer /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga
```